# if statement with content of a form

Tags: forms, comments

I searched a lot without success, i hope i can find the right answer for me.

I want to make a simple bet system, without any real money. At the time of the registration the user get x fakecredits. I decide to use the comment system to check how much the user wants to bet, so i added a field called bet to comment form.

What i want to do now is very simple as logic:

```
if (Bet < User Money){
 submit content;
}else{
 don't submit;
}
```

i already made a view that shows user money. i only need the if statement. I also created a module with module_form_alter, but i don't know what to put then.

Thanks in advance

Drupal version 7.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use another method.
I coudnl't find the way to print the input of the user, until i find this:

```
$form_state['input']['field_bet']['und'][0]['value']
```

And checked if it was greater or lesser then $user->fakemoney

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something to put in the field or form validation.

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'form_validate';
```

or

```
$form['your_field']['#element_validate'] => array('_field_callback_validate'),
```

Comment: I assume they also require the code for programatically running the view to get the user money value and then comparing it to the field value in $form_state['values'] and triggering a form error.

Comment: Sorry guys, i think i don't understand. Have i to put these in my module's php? what's the api to submit the comment?
Im not so conformtable yet with this php code :) Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Thanks :)